# Question about TeXBook Exercise 8.6

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, texbook.tex

In exercise 8.6 the characters `^^A`, `^^B`, `^^C`, `^^M` are defined to belong to categories 0, 7, 10, and 11 respectively. The question ist what tokens are produced from the input line `‘^^B^^BM^^A^^B^^C^^M^^@\M ’` (There is a space character after M). As a hint Knuth states that the line is followed by `<return>`, which is `^^M`; and that ^^@ denotes the `null` character, which has category 9.

The solution is that there are 7 tokens: [image: token list]

Why isn't the space character after the control symbol `^^B` ignored? Why does it not matter for the last control sequence that `^^M`  has category code 11?

Can anyone explain that to me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exercise assumes that `\endlinechar=13`, which corresponds to `^^M`.

When a line of input is examined (but not yet tokenized), TeX *will discard any trailing spaces along with the (system dependent) end-of-record character and insert the* `\endlinechar`.

Hence, when tokenization begins, there is *no* trailing space and you get

```
^^B^^BM^^A^^B^^C^^M^^@\M^^M
```

The `^^` convention applies during tokenization, so you get

`^^B`<sub>7</sub> `^^B`<sub>7</sub> `^^A`<sub>0</sub> `^^B`<sub>7</sub>
`^^C`<sub>10</sub> `^^M`<sub>11</sub> `^^@`<sub>9</sub> `\`<sub>0</sub> `M`<sub>11</sub> `^^M`<sub>11</sub>

However, note that tokens are formed one at a time, so TeX will not recognize two identical character of category code 7, because `^^B`<sub>7</sub> is followed by `^`, so the `^^` convention now no longer applies and you get the first two tokens of category code 7, next a control symbol `|^^B|` (the bars stand for the box used in the TeXbook), a space token that's normalized as `<space>`<sub>10</sub>. Next `^^@`<sub>9</sub> is ignored and next a control word is formed `|M^^M|`.

Comment: So why is the space after the control symbol ^^B not skipped? On page 46 it reads “TEX goes into state S in case (c), or in case (b) with respect to a character of category 10.” Does case (b) not apply here?

Comment: @horro Spaces after control symbols aren't ignored except in case of `\ `, when skipping spaces takes place. So with `\^^B` the “otherwise” case applies.